# How to transform react input value from controlled component?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to add commas to a text input as the user types.

- User typing: 1234
- Rendered Input value: 1,234

However, I'm encountering two issues.

1. React doesn't allow updating e.target.value before setState (https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/components/input#my-input-caret-jumps-to-the-beginning-on-every-keystroke)
2. If I ignore React's advice and update e.target.value directly, the cursor moves to the end even when typing in the middle of the text.

```
import {useState} from 'react';

const NumberInput = () => {
    const [value, setValue] = useState('');
    const handleChange = (event) => {
        const inputValue = event.target.value;
        setValue(
            inputValue.replace(/\D/g, '').replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ',')
        );
    };

    return <input type="text" value={value} onChange={handleChange} />;
};

export default NumberInput;
```

Is there a good approach to adding commas in a controlled component? I would appreciate any suggestions or solutions. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

your code look pretty, if you want to try more  i'll give you some option.

1. Another solution :

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function NumberInput() {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('');

  const handleInputChange = (event) => {
    const rawValue = event.target.value.replace(/\D/g, ''); // Remove non-digit characters
    const formattedValue = Number(rawValue).toLocaleString();
    setInputValue(formattedValue);
  };

  return (
    <input type="text" value={inputValue} onChange={handleInputChange} />
  );
}

export default NumberInput;
```

2. Use libary: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-number-format